# Changing the Stack Memory from C program

Tags: c

I am new to stackoverflow, so I apologize in advance for any mistakes I commit.

I have come across this C puzzle Recently. The program is given below.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void change()
{

}

int main()
{
 printf("\nHello");
 change();
 printf("\nHai");
 printf("\nHow are you?");
 return 0;
}
```

The expected output is,

```
Hello
Hai
How are you?
```

The problem asks us to change the output as follows by adding some code in function change()

```
Hello
How are you?
```

You are not supposed to make any changes in the main().

I tried to change the return address of the function change() stored in the stack memory and there by avoiding the statement printf("\nHai"). But I am getting errors when I compiled using gcc.

The code I added in change() is shown below.

```
void change()
{
 char ch;
 *(&ch+10)+=20;
}
```

The values added to ch (10 and 20) are fixed by using

```
objdump -d ./a.out
```

I hope to receive some suggestions to solve the problem. Thanking you in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: Could you post the errors you get?

Comment: You first need to disassemble to check where exactly in the stack the return value is stored.

Comment: I consider it a poor "puzzle" if you have to rely on undefined behaviour to achieve the result. Such knowledge is not worth anything, unless you are into system security professionally.

Comment: That's easy, just add `printf("\nHow are you?"); exit(0);` to `change()`

Comment: Please include the specific error you are getting (bus error?)-- also, the OS and version number.  If it is causing a signal, does the signal happen when you update the stack or when you return from the function?

Comment: The error says "segmentation fault"

Comment: @Praetorian: LOL... OK, I admit defeat and retract my earlier comment. Beautiful! :-D I got caught in the OP's line of thinking.

Comment: @EmilTom please answer ALL the questions by antlersoft, not only one ;)

Comment: @EmilTom From your question, I understand that you would like to skip over a execution step. In this case, you are trying skip in program space i.e. `.text` region and not `stack`. I am not sure if updating stack pointer would actually help in this case.

Comment: @Ganesh you're totally wrong my friend. The return address of a function is stored in the stack. Check [this](http://fr33kk0mpu73r.blogspot.com.es/2012/11/understanding-buffer-overflows-i.html).

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, the return address/program counter is in stack pointer only if there was a function call. For the given example, yes you are right. My approach was more on incrementing the PC instead of SP.

Comment: @Ganesh The entry point is a function (`main()`) so there's always a function call.

Comment: I disagree with "poor puzzle" and closing the question. The offsets in answer are indeed localized but the technique to derive them is universal. This would be a good illustration of stack layout and low-level C techniques, it can be useful to many users.

Comment: @glagolig I agree with glagolig. Any "make something which does X do Y instead, under these constraints" is a valid problem. Undefined behavior just means that the ISO C document doesn't provide an opinion about the behavior. It doesn't mean undefined on an absolute level to the point that your computer's gates become meta-stable when you run it. For instance, if we obtain an assembly language translation from a compiler, and then throw away the original C, we can perfectly discuss the behavior of the assembly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code puzzles are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: `fclose(stdout)`?

Comment: It tried https://pastebin.com/SpjpbpUf with some debugging info, and it looks like I'm correctly rewriting the return address at the right location and to the right value (when compiling at x86-64 with -O0, anyway), but it doesn't seem to be having an effect. Interesting problem.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. The following is on linux on x86-64.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change()
{
    char dummy;

    /* skip local variable and rbp */
    *(long*)(&dummy + sizeof(dummy) + sizeof(long*)) += 0x40055e - 0x400554;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    change();
    printf("Hi\n");
    printf("How are you?\n");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
$ gcc -fno-stack-protector -o main main.c
$ ./main
Hello
How are you?
```

from objdump we get:

```
    40054f: e8 c8 ff ff ff          callq  40051c <change>
->  400554: bf 1a 06 40 00          mov    $0x40061a,%edi
    400559: e8 92 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <puts@plt>
->  40055e: bf 1e 06 40 00          mov    $0x40061e,%edi
    400563: e8 88 fe ff ff          callq  4003f0 <puts@plt>
```

Process:

First use a small arbitrary difference in `main.c`. Then compile and run `objdump -d main` to get the actual offsets and update `main.c` with their difference.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should achieve the desired effect.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void change()
{
printf("\nHow are you?"); 
exit(0);
}

int main()
{
 printf("\nHello");
 change();
 printf("\nHai");
 printf("\nHow are you?");
 return 0;
}
```

This code will cause the program to print "Hello" then execute the change() function which will print "How are you?" on a newline and then exit the program. The exit() function is part of the c standard library as can be seen [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/)